# Oracle: how to get unique combinations of 2 sets

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, combinations

sample data:

```
create table group_ (
group_id number);

create table set_(
set_id number);

insert into group_ values(1);
insert into set_ values(1);
insert into set_ values(2);
insert into set_ values(3);
```

Data looks like
group: 1
set: 1,2,3

I want to get all combinations of this 2 tables but UNIQUE ( 1,2,3 it's same as 1,3,2), so output would be like this:

```
    1
    1-1
    1-2
    1-3
    1-12
    1-13
    1-23
    1-123
```

I tried using connect_by_path, but it get's me or same combinations (like 1-132) or some combinations are missing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have duplicated values in `set_` and that you missed `1-23` in the expected result, this could be a way:

```
select to_char(group_id)
from group_
UNION ALL
select to_char(group_id) || '-' || replace (sys_connect_by_path(to_char(set_id), ' '), ' ', '')
from set_
    cross join group_
connect by prior set_id < set_id
```

Comment: Of course I missed one combination. Thank You very much! :)

Comment: 1 question - for 3 group and 2 sets a iget a few repeated combinations. Why ?